# Condition doesn't work

Tags: ios

I use button in `ViewController` to go `TableViewController`. In `TableViewController` I create `int` NInt1. But when I go to `TableViewController` condition doesn't work.

`ViewController.m`

```
- (IBAction)Button:(id)sender {
MasterViewController *trns =[[MasterViewController alloc]init];
[_Button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"1"];
    trns.NInt1=1;
}
```

`TableViewController.m`

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if(_NInt1 == 1){
    return 5;
}else{
    return 20;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you use xib or storyboard?

Comment: See my below answer.Let me know.

Comment: See the differences between my answer and below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the story pass the value like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.NInt1 = 1;
}
```

Now see the value of NInt in viewDidLoad of your destination view controller.

Comment: ya for that you have to take one global variable which tell that which IBAction was called

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to modify like

```
- (IBAction)Button:(UIButton *)sender {
 MasterViewController *trns =[[MasterViewController alloc]init];
if [sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"1"]{
  trns.NInt1=1;
 }
}
```

on that `tableviewController` viewDidload check like use `NSLog` for the object is `1` or not

Comment: while moving into the TableviewController.what is the value of 'NInt1'.can you check with `NSLog` in viewdidload.If it is Nil Check with `sender.titleLabel.text`

Answer (score 0):

If you use storyboard, then the destination view controller is not created from your `IBAction`. It can be verified easily : you never push or present the newly created view controller, which is local in your method.

Instead use `prepareForSegue`method as described in Jaimish answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution.Finally I got.Thank you.The condition has worked now.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"goTableViewController"])
  {
    TableViewController *tableVC = (TableViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
    tableVC.NInt1 = 5;
  }
}
```